# Test with PHPUnit Laravel 5 controller with database (Mock?)

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-5

I would like to Unit test one of my controller and I'm wondering how to do that without impacting the database. Here are my files :

Route:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksListController');
```

In my TasksListController:

```
public function store()
{
    if (empty(Input::get('name')) || !isset(Input::get('name'))) {
        return false;
    }
    if (Task::create(Input::all())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My form:

```
        <form action="/tasks" name="task" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
        </form>
```

My Unit Test:

```
class TasksTest extends TestCase {

    public function testAddTask()
    {
        // How can I test the task creation ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing your controller, you can mock the Task class:

```
Task::shouldReceive('create')->with([])->once()->andReturn('mocked-task');
```

Normally, a controller returns a view or a redirect object, but in this situation your return is a boolean just do the assert:

```
$response = $this->call('post', 'tasks');
$this->assertTrue($response->getContent());
```